# Evaluate string expression in Java with two numbers using recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

I'm having a problem with multiplying a positive number with a negative number from a string expression.

If my expression is `-4*5` then it returns -20 but if I put `4*-5` then it returns -5 instead of -20.

I did a bit of debugging and found that my substring only picked up the -5 but there was no number after the * operator so it returned 0.0

I thought of checking for the negative sign before the expression gets executed and determining whether it's a negative number or not. However, it did not as expected.

Could I please get some help?

```
if (expression.contains("-")) 
{
    int indexOfExpression = expression.lastIndexOf('-');
    String beforeMinus = expression.substring(indexOfExpression-1,indexOfExpression);
    if(beforeMinus.equals("*") || beforeMinus.equals("/")) 
    {
        double afterMinus = Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(indexOfExpression,indexOfExpression+2));
        return afterMinus;
    }else {
            double rhs = evaluate(expression.substring(indexOfExpression+1));
            return evaluate(expression.substring(0, indexOfExpression)) - rhs;
    }
} else if (expression.contains("*")) {
    int indexOfExpression = expression.lastIndexOf("*");
    Double rhs = evaluate(expression.substring(indexOfExpression + 1));;
    return evaluate(expression.substring(0, indexOfExpression)) *rhs;
}
```

This is what I currently have and the output is -5 instead of -20.

Comment: in `substring(indexOfExpression-,indexOfExpression)` did you mean to say `substring(indexOfExpression-1,indexOfExpression)`? but if indexOfExpression is 0 that would be an invalid index for substring

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. That was meant to be -1. I might have deleted it by accident when I was formatting the code.

Comment: In the case where there is a "*" or "/" the current code just returns the value after the operator (modulo the error @AlwaysLearning mentioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of errors in the code, so I think it makes more sense to answer from the perspective of how could this be done better rather than just debugging. I'll assume you want to perform a binary operation of two number seperated by one of the four operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. The main difficulty is the ambiguity between `-` as an operator and `-` as a symbol for a negative number (in which case it's more like multiplication by `-1` than subtraction). The following isn't meant to be a bullet-proof algorithm, but to give you an idea of a more structured approach to the problem.

```java
class Operator {
    public String op;
    public int index;
}

Operator findOperator(String expression) {
    // Assumes that 'expression' is a simple expression of the form:
    //      <number><op><number>
    // Find all instances of '+', '-', '*', '/'.
    // If '-' appears one or more times with another symbol, the other one is
    // the operator. If more than one '-' appears, determine which is the
    // operator based on position (e.g. can't be the operator at index zero).
    return new Operator(...);
}

double calculate(String op, String lhs, String rhs) {
    double left = Double.parseDouble(lhs);
    double right = Double.parseDouble(rhs);
    switch (op) {
    case "+":
        return left + right;
    // etc.
    }
}

double calculate(String expression) {
    Operator operator = findOperator(expression);
    return calculate(
            operator.op,
            expression.substring(0, operator.index),
            expression.substring(operator.index + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll have a go at it.

Comment: Did this approach turn out to be helpful? Need clarification on anything?

Comment: Thank you for checking up on me, this was really helpful. I used this and completed my project.